# Grant rights to every table in a scheme every time a new table is created

Tags: postgresql

The problem is when new table is created, the user of the schema dont have access to it.
I want to create a trigger which is started everytime when a new table is being created.
Every user should have read rights to the new table.

I tried some trigger events but they didnt worked.. maybe you can help.

Comment: Did you set the default permissions? You don't need a trigger for this, that's for sure

Comment: i did set the read permission for the scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default permissions for the new tables created in the future:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA your_schema 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO your_user;
```

This role must have usage permissions on the schema as well.

Comment: where i need to run this?

Comment: In your database, that's where you control the permissions. You can use psql or any other PostgreSQL client for this.

Comment: It doesnt changed anything

Comment: Did you execute this query in the same database? Did you create a new table afterwards? And what error message did you get when your database role tried to access the new table?